# Dividing a vector to form different matrices

Tags: matlab

I have a two long vector. Vector one contains values of 0,1,2,3,4's, 0 represent no action, 1 represent action 1 and 2 represent the second action and so on. Each action is 720 sample point which means that you could find 720 consecutive twos then 720 consecutive 4s for example. Vector two contains raw data corresponding to each action. I need to create a matrix for each action ( 1, 2, 3 and 4) which contains the corresponding data of the second vector. For example matrix 1 should has all the data (vector 2 data) which occurred at the same indices of action 1. Any Help??

```
Example on small amount of data:
Vector 1: 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 2 
Vector 2: 6 7 5 6 4 6 5 9 8 7 9 7 0 5 6 4 1 5 8 0
Result:
Matrix 1:
5 6 4 
0 5 6
Matrix 2:
9 8 7 
5 8 0
```

Comment: How do you choose when to make a new row in `Matrix 1` and `Matrix 2`? Are there always going to be the right number of elements to do that?

Comment: All actions have the same length as shown in the example. but the real data is much longer

Comment: So each group of 1's will always have length 3, and those 3 will correspond to the length of each row of the output matrix?

Comment: exactly. and the same for the other actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach. I used a cell array to store the output matrices, hard-coding names for such variables isn't a good plan.

```
V1=[0 0 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 2]
V2=[6 7 5 6 4 6 5 9 8 7 9 7 0 5 6 4 1 5 8 0]

%// Find length of sequences of 1's/2's
len=find(diff(V1(find(diff(V1)~=0,1)+1:end))~=0,1)

I=unique(V1(V1>0)); %// This just finds how many matrices to make, 1 and 2 in this case
C=bsxfun(@eq,V1,I.'); %// The i-th row of C contains 1's where there are i's in V1
%// Now pick out the elements of V2 based on C, and store them in cell arrays
Matrix=arrayfun(@(m) reshape(V2(C(m,:)),len,[]).',I,'uni',0);
%// Note, the reshape converts from a vector to a matrix

%// Display results
Matrix{1}
Matrix{2}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but It gives me an error "Product of known dimensions, 720, not divisible into total number of elements, 852" 
Is there is a way I can check the number of consecutive elements in the array to make sure it is 720??

Comment: See edit, it's not a great way of doing it I don't think, but it's the best I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

Since, there is a regular pattern in the lengths of groups within `Vector 1`, that could be exploited to `vectorize` many things while proposing a solution. Here's one such implementation -

```
%// Form new vectors out of input vectors for non-zero elements in vec1
vec1n = vec1(vec1~=0)
vec2n = vec2(vec1~=0)

%// Find positions of group shifts and length of groups 
df1 = diff(vec1n)~=0
grp_change = [true df1]
grplen = find(df1,1)

%// Reshape vec2n, so that we end up with N x grplen sized array 
vec2nr = reshape(vec2n,grplen,[]).'  %//'

%// ID/tag each group change based on their unique vector 2 values
[R,C] = sort(vec1n(grp_change))

%// Re-arrange rows of reshaped vector2, s.t. same ID rows are grouped succesively
vec2nrs = vec2nr(C,:)

%// Find extents of each group & use those extents to have final cell array output
grp_extent = diff(find([1 diff(R) 1]))
out = mat2cell(vec2nrs,grp_extent,grplen)
```

Sample run for the given inputs -

```
>> vec1
vec1 =
     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     2     2     2  ...
             0     0     1     1     1     0     0     2     2     2
>> vec2
vec2 =
     6     7     5     6     4     6     5     9     8     7  ...
             9     7     0     5     6     4     1     5     8     0
>> celldisp(out)
out{1} =
     5     6     4
     0     5     6
out{2} =
     9     8     7
     5     8     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
v1 = [0 0 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 2];
v2 = [6 7 5 6 4 6 5 9 8 7 9 7 0 5 6 4 1 5 8 0];

m1 = reshape(v2(v1 == 1), 3, [])'
m2 = reshape(v2(v1 == 2), 3, [])'
```

EDIT:  David's solution is more flexible and probably more efficient.